# Change the command prompt on entering a command

Tags: linux

I need to be able to change the prompt on running an executable of a c file to get a custom prompt

E.g:

$ abc

abc>

Here the user can give the commands acceptable to the program.
I saw this happen for programs like MySQL and was wondering if it is possible to do this.

Comment: You need to pipe your input into the program
something like `$abc | 'your input here'`

Comment: Sorry, this is not clear: do you want to write your own program to accept user input or to change the prompt of the existing program?

Comment: Basically, I need to implement a ftp client-server. So when the user issues a command like %myftp server-host-name server-port-number, the client process should respond with a prompt
ftp>
waiting for the user's ftp commands

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can include the [readline library](http://cnswww.cns.cwru.edu/php/chet/readline/readline.html#SEC23) in your program to make it have a modern command line interface.

Or you can simply build a loop get each line from input and get the tokens from that line of input to execute commands, and there printout your `abc>` prompt.

Answer (score 2):

You can use gnu [readline](http://cnswww.cns.cwru.edu/php/chet/readline/rltop.html) for custom prompt

```
#include <readline/readline.h>
#include <readline/history.h>


while (1)
{
   command = readline ("$abc");
   command = readline ("abc>");
   //validate your command name
   system(command);
   add_history (command); ///add command in history
}
```